# Javascript variable function method call

Tags: javascript, cordova

I apologise if this has been asked elsewhere, I looked but without knowing the name for what I am doing is, I couldn't find anything.

Anyways, the code is as follows:

```
function alertTypeOptions(AlertType, AlertOptions) {
    navigator.notification.AlertType(AlertOptions);
}
```

This code is for a phonegap / cordova application.

The basic idea is that you pass the function a two variables and these are used to execute the appropriate method. Examples of this could be alertTypeOptions('beep', '3') or alertTypeOptions('vibrate', '2000'). This (should) play the default alert tone 3x or vibrate the phone for 2 seconds.

I am currently getting the following error:

```
02-21 15:36:07.185: E/Web Console(7206): Uncaught TypeError:
Object #<Object> has no method 'AlertType'
at file:///android_asset/www/res/scripts.js:181
```

Obviously the function is currently just using the alertType variable as written rather than as a variable.

Is there a way to get this to work elegantly? Currently my only thoughts are to use a switch statement with AlertType as the check.

Jack

Comment: What's alertoptions ?

Comment: It depends on the method that is being called. If its vibrate it will be the length of time that the phone should vibrate for. The details are here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to access your function using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) :

```
navigator.notification[AlertType](AlertOptions);
```

or rather, if I trust [this documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html) and if `AlertOptions` is an array :

```
navigator.notification[AlertType].apply(navigator, AlertOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks. Was fairly sure it would be something simple, I just wasn't sure what to look for.

I'll accept your answer when the timer is up

Comment: @Jack Did you check it ? Id didn't see in the documentation the possibility to pass an options object.

Comment: It works with the current set, I'm just reading into the array possibilities

Comment: If it works the first way, don't lose time with the second one (apart if you just want to understand it).